# How to plot svm hyperplane with only one feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, data-analysis

I have a dataset with one feature and I'm using scikit-learn train a support vector classifier. I'd like to visualize the results, but I'm a little bit perplexed on how to plot the scatter. I'm getting my hyperplane by doing the following:

```
slope = clf.coef_[0][0]
intercept = clf.intercept_[0]
```

Which gives me y = -.01x + 2.5

I'm assuming this is my hyperplane. I can't seem to figure out how to plot my data around this with only one feature. What would I use for my y-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting problem. On the surface it's very simple — one feature means one dimension, hence the hyperplane has to be 0-dimensional, i.e. a point. Yet what scikit-learn gives you is a line. So the question is really how to turn this line into a point.

I've spent about an hour looking for answers in the documentation for scikit-learn, but there is simply nothing on 1-d SVM classifiers (probably because they are not practical). So I decided to play with the sample code below to see if I can figure out the answer:

```
from sklearn import svm

n_samples = 100
X = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0,0.1,n_samples), np.random.normal(10,0.1,n_samples)]).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array([0]*n_samples+[1]*n_samples)
clf = svm.LinearSVC(max_iter = 10000)
clf.fit(X,y)  
slope = clf.coef_
intercept = clf.intercept_
print(slope, intercept)
print(-intercept/slope)
```

`X` is the array of samples such that the first 100 points are sampled from N(0,0.1), and the next 100 points are sampled from N(10,0.1). `y` is the array of labels (100 of class '0' and 100 of class '1'). Intuitively it's clear the hyperplane should be halfway between 0 and 10.

Once you fit the classifier, you find out the intercept is about -0.96 which is nowhere near where the 0-d hyperplane (i.e. a point) should be. However, if you take `y=0` and back-calculate `x`, it will be pretty close to 5. Now try changing the means of the distributions that make up X, and you will find that the answer is always `-intercept/slope`. That's your 0-d hyperplane (point) for the classifier.

So to visualize, you merely need to plot your data on a number line (use different colours for the classes), and then plot the boundary obtained by dividing the negative intercept by the slope. I'm not sure how to plot a number line, but you can always resort to a scatter plot with all `y` coordinates set to 0.